# Log in Profile in python

Tags: python

Is there any way that we can print the user name of the person who has logged in the system in the file? the file is an output file of python.

Comment: This question is not clear. Can you explain a little more clearly?

Comment: What do you mean? To get the current user name from a Python program? or create a daemon that logs all log-ins? Which OS?

Comment: i will not mind both..but right now, only the one who is connected to the system..it is WINDOWS -XP..so may not be tough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into `os.environ`.

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.environ['LOGNAME']
Out[2]: 'lev'
```

Comment: throws an error: KeyError: 'LOGNAME'

Comment: @peterparker KeyError? Try `USERNAME` then ([source](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-windows-xps-environment-variables/5986211)). Or print out the whole `os.environ` and see what's in there.

Comment: i had tried that also, still the same error..i think something else is also needed..

Comment: PS C:\Users\rk\lpthw> python username.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "username.py", line 3, in <module>
    print os.environ['LOGNAME']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 423, in __getitem__
    return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'LOGNAME'
PS C:\Users\rk\lpthw>

Comment: Like I said, you could try `USERNAME` instead of `LOGNAME` or just `print os.environ`.

Comment: yes, directly printing os.environ does solves the problem :)..thanks for the help